# Is it just me, or does domain driven design fall apart in large enterprise architectures?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm pretty sure I understand domain driven design, if you have a dog and it needs to bark, put a bark method on dog. If the dog's state needs to be persisted, that's the job of a repository. I know there's more, but let's just go with that for now.

I see things in enterprise systems to work from the business process to the capabilities that allow the process to complete. I've seen business processes that take one complete calendar year to complete and the state of that process is maintained in a business process management system (BPMS).

So the BPMS executes capabilities throughout the year based on scheduled times. Some of these capabilities are reused in other business processes. The objects that are candidates to be involved in DDD (our humble dog) have no idea what the process is, they just need to bark when given the inputs from the process. How does a DDD help with this when the dog just needs to bark when we ask him to, given certain inputs by the process?

Comment: If anything, DDD is about making the model and the processes within it explicit. Because one part of the model is not fully capturing all the details of the process it's part of, does not imply the model or parts thereof are not useful.

Comment: You go back to OO basics and draw state models. See my blog post http://priscimon.com/blog/2012/04/19/a-gentle-introduction-to-model-based-development/.

Comment: Yves, I agree with your comment but it seems like this would result in many micro domains and not in a comprehensive understanding of the big picture. It seems like DDD's value is in knowing the big picture which is impossible in large enterprise applications. This may be where I'm misunderstanding it though.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer, just some notes:

> if you have a dog and it needs to bark, put a bark method on dog

This is oversimplification. Objects in code should not try to mimic real world as if our binary dog could actually jump out of monitor and start barking. In software world, [square is not a rectangle](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/). More likely that you are interested in fact that dog has barked, about dog barking rate changes in time.

And suddenly, we are talking about barking history records, about medical state description - about information, not artificial wannabe real life objects.